# Is it possible to edit a profile?

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

I've created my profile and I've been using it for a long time. Today, I decided to change my profile picture and change the email address I used when signing up and it turns out I can't.

Note: Pls, I'm new here, so I'm actually not sure if this is where I am supposed to be posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can find the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials).

Basically add a login credential and delete the old.

Comment: You've clearly highlighted how to edit my login credentials but is there a way to change my profile picture

Comment: Well...yeah. click on edit profile in your profile, then click the "change picture" link at the bottom of your picture. Apologies, I missed that part.

Comment: Now that's more satisfying, thanks